# StringRegExp pattern | Get text inside brackets

Tags: regex, autoit

Its Just a short question, because i cant handle with that.
I have an example string like that:

> $String = '[{test:["0","xx"],test2:["11","23"]}]'

And what i want to do, is to write function, which will give me text in brackets. It should write it to Array.

The functon which i am trying to write looks like that:

> $avArray = getStringInsideBracketsKW($String,'[',']')

```
func getStringInsideBracketsKW($string, $openBracket, $closeBracket)

    $NewAvArray = StringRegExp($string,'/\'&$openBracket&'.*?\'&$closeBracket&'/g')

    Return $NewAvArray 


EndFunc
```

So now - what is wron with this function?
I am not good at RegExp patterns but i am sure that is the best method to do what I want.

**@EDIT**

Because it is in AutoIt it have to be smth like that:

> $NewAvArray = StringRegExp($string,'[.*?]',3)

It will result me :

> $NewAvArray[0] = '[{test:["0","xx"]' ;
>
> $NewAvArray[1] = '["11,"23"]';

But i want a result like:

```
$NewAvArray[0] = '{test:["0","xx"],test2:["11","23"]}'
```

Because i want an Array,which show what is exactly in these two brackets.

Comment: Why not just use _StringBetween ?

Comment: becouse it will find the string between first '[' and than the nearest ']'. I want to find a container of that list. So when it will be like [x[aa]t] i want a result x[aa]t. And when string be like '[x[aa]][a[]]' i want at a result an Array with $avArray[0] = x[aa], and $avArray[1] = a[]

Comment: Why don't you write it from scratch?
Find all $b's for all $a's and extract the outer ones.

Comment: My StringRegExp example is working just like you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
#include <Array.au3>


$sString = "Bob Parker [B[dd]P]" & @CRLF & "Fred Bloggs [FB]"


$aArray = StringRegExp($sString, "[\(\[](.*)[/)\]]", 3)


_ArrayDisplay($Aarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
    $NewAvArray = BinaryToString(string("$string,'/\'&$openBracket&'.*?  \'&$closeBracket&'/g'))
    $aRes=_StringBetween($Source,"[","]")
    _ArrayDisplay($aRes)
```

Comment: Please add more details to make your answer more useful for readers.

Comment: It is impossible to do smth like this in AutoIt. I mean that construction. I have checked if it find a pattern like that:
`$NewAvArray = StringRegExp($string,'/\'&$openBracket&'.*?  \'&$closeBracket&'/g')`

And there is no found elements ;/

Comment: You are mixing your expectations. First exampele: Get all between the first and the last bracket. But than, you mentioned [x[aa]][a[]] this should be handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with a regular language, as there are not a finite number of states (there are theoretically infinite numbers of nested brackets). I have heard about some regex extensions adding support for nested matches, but I don't know of anything like that in AutoIt.

Regex really isn't suitable for this sort of text manipulation, why not just code a function to do it manually? It'll be a bit slower probably, but you can be sure that it does the right thing. This one took me 10 minutes, and could probably be made faster by removing the need for redimming 2 different arrays. The need for an `$aStack` variable shows why you can't use traditional regex for this.

```
#include <Array.au3>

Local $sTest = "H[e[l]l]o [W[o[r]ld]]!"
Local $aRet = _StringBetweenOuter($sTest, "[", "]")

_ArrayDisplay($aRet)

Func _StringBetweenOuter($sString, $sStart, $sEnd)
    Local $aRet[1] = [0]

    If $sStart = $sEnd Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0) ; Start = End

    Local $iPos = 1, $iNextStart, $iNextEnd, $aStack[1] = [0], $iStart
    While 1
        $iNextStart = StringInStr($sString, $sStart, 0, 1, $iPos)
        $iNextEnd = StringInStr($sString, $sEnd, 0, 1, $iPos)

        If $iNextEnd = 0 Then ExitLoop

        If $iNextEnd < $iNextStart Or $iNextStart = 0 Then
            If $aStack[0] < 1 Then
                Return SetError(2, $iNextEnd, 0) ; Unbalanced starts and ends
            EndIf

            $iStart = _ArrayPop($aStack)
            $aStack[0] -= 1

            If $aStack[0] = 0 Then
                _ArrayAdd($aRet, StringMid($sString, $iStart, $iNextEnd - $iStart))
                $aRet[0] += 1
            EndIf

            $iPos = $iNextEnd + 1
        Else
            _ArrayAdd($aStack, $iNextStart + 1)
            $aStack[0] += 1

            $iPos = $iNextStart + 1
        EndIf
    WEnd

    Return $aRet
EndFunc   ;==>_StringBetweenOuter
```

Comment: You are rignt. RegExp is not usefull here. I wrote a kind of function like you. But it is too slow. May yours be a little bit faster :) Thank You!